# Qt4 "dependent" error

Tags: c++, qt

I already have QtCreator and Qt5 installed on my computer, but today I need to use qt4 instead, so I've downloaded "Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (VS 2010, 234 MB)" from http://qt-project.org/downloads, added Qt profile for Qt4 and tried to compile my project. But I got following error:

> ... C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.1\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
>
> Error: dependent '-' does not exist.
>
> jom: C:\Users\User\Desktop\OS-build-Qt_4_8_4_msvc2010-**__**\Makefile
>   [release] Error 2 ...

Why? What does it mean?

Comment: What's full path and name of .pro file? Because that looks like the project name is somehow empty...

Comment: You also may get into trouble with long paths. Some of msvc tools still have crazy limits on path lengths.  I would not build from the desktop.

Comment: @hyde OS.pro is the full name of .pro file

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, the project doesn't build from desktop, but can build from D:/OS folder... Why?

Comment: I am leaning towards some character in the path that is causing jom to fail.